# How to implement a named constructor in ES6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-class

I am trying to implement named constructor usage in ES6. The reason for this is that I thought it would be more pleasing to avoid the constructor invocation with `new` keyword and instead use a simple method of the class to make use of other methods. I thought of using a static function for this as a `Proxy` for the constructor.

I tried the following:

```js
class Person {
  constructor(...props) {
    let {name, age} = props;
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
  }
  static create(...props) {
    return new Person(props);
  }
  
  display() {
    console.log(this)
  }
}

Person.create({name: 'John', age: 28}).display(); //Simple object input
```

But this won't work as simple object input gives:

```
Person {name: undefined, age: undefined}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

**Update**: Thanks, the answer by @appleapple helped a lot. I didn't notice the fact that I was passing a single argument. For those who are wondering how this could be done for n-Ary constructor method(of course using an object is neat, but still), here is an example:

```js
class Person {
  constructor([name, age ]) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
  }
  static create(...props) {
    return new Person(props); //return new this(props); also works
  }
  
  display() {
    console.log(this)
  }
}

Person.create('John', 28).display();
```

Comment: constructor( [name, age] ) just provides people a way to create a person named '28' with age 'John'. most IDE's will provide information on parameters, if you give them sensible names, everyone's life will be easier for it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

not that complex, object is a single argument, so just pass it around.

```js
class Person {
  constructor(props) { // <-------
    let {name, age} = props;
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
  }
  static create(props) { // <-------
    return new Person(props); 
  }

  display() {
    console.log(this)
  }
}

Person.create({name: 'John', age: 28}).display();
```

Comment: `constructor ({ name, age }) {
  this.name = name;
  this.age = age;
}` works as well.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts no much difference. Besides, not relevant to this Q I think.

Answer (score 0):

reply to your update, actually you can forward the arguments (and I think the constructor looks better in this case)

```js
class Person {
  constructor(name, age) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
  }
  static create(...props) {
    return new Person(...props); // <----------
  }
  
  display() {
    console.log(this)
  }
}

Person.create('John', 28).display();
```

---

or you can also take rest parameter in constructor (I don't like this, though)

```js
class Person {
  constructor(...props) {  // <----------
    let [name, age]=props
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
  }
  static create(...props) {
    return new Person(...props); // <----------
  }
  
  display() {
    console.log(this)
  }
}

Person.create('John', 28).display();
```